# expanding arbitrary number of sublists within a list

Tags: python

I am trying to expand sublists within a list. I wrote it for one layer of sublists within the list. Is there a better way to code this so to scale for arbitrary number of nested lists? See example as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [a, b]

def expand(x):
    # expands a list of lists with no further sublists 
    a = []
    for i in x:
        # could also here do a += i and avoid the second for loop
        for j in i:
            a.append(j)
    return a

print expand(c)
```

Returns the desired `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

To further clarify, I am wondering how to better scale for

`e = [c, a, b]' and further nested iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

# first method
res = [x for lst in c for x in lst]

# second method
from itertools import chain
res = list(chain(*c))
```

**Edit:** he wants *iteratively nested* lists!

```
c = [[[1], [2, 3]], [4, 5], [[6, 7, 8], 9]]

def expand(lst):
    try:
        for a in lst:
            for b in expand(a):
                yield b
    except TypeError:
        yield lst

res = list(expand(c))   # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: +1 for the itertools method.  I believe that itertools and collections are two of the most powerful but underused modules in python's stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

Use Recursion:

```
def flat_list(l):
    for a in l:
        if isinstance(a, list):
            for x in flat_list(a):
                yield x
        else:
            yield a

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [a, b]
e = [c, a, b]

print list(flat_list(c))
print list(flat_list(e))
```

the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
def flatten(ls):
        result = []
        stack = [ls]
        while stack:
            if isinstance(stack[-1], list):
                try: stack.append(stack[-1].pop(0))
                except IndexError: stack.pop() # remove now-empty sublist
            else:
                result.append(stack.pop())
        return result

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [a, b]
e = [c, a, b]

print flatten(e)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or :

Using sum:

```
>>> e
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> sum(e[0], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Using reduce:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, e[0])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```